# Is there a design pattern to handle when code depends on the subtype of two objects

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I'll try to be as explicit as possible, in case there is a better solution for my problem than answering my question.

I'm working in C#.

I have a report template that can include any number of 'features' turned on. A feature might be a table of information, a pie/bar chart, a list, etc. I am generating the report as a text file, or a PDF (possibly other options in the future).

So far I have an `IFeature` interface, and some feature types implementing it: `ChartFeature`, `ListFeature`, etc.
I read the list of features enabled from the database and pass each one to a method along with the data id and the method returns a populated `IFeature` of the proper type.

I also have an `IReportWriter` interface that `TextReportWriter` and PdfReportWriter implement. That interface has a method: `AddFeature(IFeature)`.

The problem is that `AddFeature` in each writer ends up looking like:

```
public void AddFeature(IFeature)
{
    InsertSectionBreakIfNeeded();

    if(IFeature is TableFeature)
    {
        TableFeature tf = (TableFeature)feature;
        streamWriter.WriteLine(tf.Title);
        for(int row=0; row < tf.Data.First.Length; row++)
        {
            for(int column=0; i < tf.Data.Length; i++)
            {
                if(i != 0)
                {
                    streamWriter.Write("|");
                }
                streamWriter.Write(feature.Data[column][row]);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(IFeature is ListFeature)
    {
        ListFeature lf = (ListFeature)feature;
        streamWriter.Write(lf.Title + ": ");
        bool first = true;
        foreach(var v in lf.Data)
        {
            if(!first)
            {
                streamWriter.Write(", ");
            }
            else
            {
                first = false;
            }
            streamWriter.Write(v);
        }
    }
    ...
    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    sectionBreakNeeded = true;
}
```

In the PDF writer the above would be modified to generate PDF table cells, text boxes, and so forth.

This feels ugly. I like it somewhat better as `AddFeature(ListFeature){...}`, `AddFeature(ChartFeature)` because at least then it's compile time checked, but in practice it just moves the problem so now outside if the IReportWriter I'm calling `if(feature is ...)`.

Moving the display code into the feature just reverses the problem because it would need to know whether it should be writing plain text or a PDF.

Any suggestions, or am I best just using what I have and ignoring my feelings?

Edit:
Filled in some of the conditions to give people a better idea of what is happening. Don't worry too much about the exact code in those examples, I just wrote it off the top of my head.

Comment: Whay exactly do you need all this conditionals?

Comment: Look at Builder and Strategy Patterns. Builder is used to build complex objects and Strategy is used to define algorithms and you can encapsulate each one and make them interchangeable..

Comment: @Henrique: Because the different categories of features need to be displayed differently, and may contain different types of data. That is why they are sub typed as well.

Comment: For me, for now it's an XY problem :\

Comment: Looks kind of like the Double Dispatch and the Visitor pattern. If you follow this idea, in your AddFeature you just call back the feature methods, passing the writer as a parameter. The description of what these ifs do is however too vague to be sure.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I'm not familiar with those patterns but I'll look them up, and I'll fill in my code a bit more.

Comment: You really want to use inheritance for this, not a if else if else ladder.  You do NOT want to write any code that depends on the type of the object if you can avoid it.  You need a method that adds an `IFeature` to the `IReport`.  You could use the factory pattern to create and return the desired `IFeature`.

Comment: @TonyVitabile I know I want to avoid such code, that's why it feels bad to me and why I asked thee question.  I have a factory that creates and returns the desired IFeature, the problem is that: Every report type needs it's own code for every feature / every feature needs it's own code for every report type.

Comment: Given what you've said, the Visitor pattern in Chris Tavares' answer looks like a good solution for you.  I'm upvoting it.

Comment: Agreed it looks right. Marking as the answer for now. If I run into problems with it I'll revisit this.

Comment: Define IReportWriter and have your features implement it :/  I like that better than adding a visitor because you don't have to rewrite your friggen visitor when you add another implementation of IFeature.

Comment: @Will Assuming that there wasn't much commonality between the writers (writing to a text stream, vs a PDF are somewhat different), what you're suggesting becomes essentially: `ChartFeature.WriteToReport(IReportWriter) { IReportWriter.DrawChart(this); }` and that's (nearly) the visitor pattern.

Comment: My overriding goal is that if I want to add a new X I don't have to rewrite Y to add another method/if statement/etc.  So, in your case, I'd define IFeature as `IFeature : IReportWriter`, or I'd have a `ReportWriterAttribute` that, if it wasn't defined on a particular implementation of IFeature, I'd throw an IOE.  So any time you add another feature, you just add another writer, and you're done. The Aristocrats.

Comment: @Will - *So any time you add another feature, you just add another writer, and you're done.* Wouldn't you have to write N new writers, where N = the number of report formats? The code to output a GIF is very different from the code to output a PDF which is very different from the code to output plain text.

Comment: @ChrisTavares You assume the report writer is writing the final result and not just writing out details in a common format which is then saved by another component in 1..n output types. Come on, you don't need me to tell you the obvious.

Comment: Why does the `ChartFeature` condition use `TableFeature`? Is that a typo?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator yes that was a typo. I had written the conditionals and then someone had asked for a sample of what they would include so I quickly filled in some code - guess I didn't match it up. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general case of your problem is called double-dispatch - you need to dispatch to a method based on the runtime type of two parameters, not just one (the "this" pointer).

One standard pattern to deal with this is called the Visitor pattern. It's description traces back to the original Design Patterns book, so there's lots of example and analysis of it out there.

The basic idea is that you have two general things - you have the Elements (which are the things that you're processing) and Visitors, which process over the Elements. You need to do dynamic dispatch over both of them - so the actual method called varies depending on both the concrete type of the element and of the visitor.

In C#, and kinda sorta following your example, you'd define an IFeatureVisitor interface like this:

```
public interface IFeatureVisitor {
    void Visit(ChartFeature feature);
    void Visit(ListFeature feature);
    // ... etc one per type of feature
}
```

Then, in your IFeature interface, add an "Accept" method.

```
public interface IFeature {
    public void Accept(IFeatureVisitor visitor);
}
```

Your feature implementations would implement the Accept method like so:

```
public class ChartFeature : IFeature {
    public void Accept(IFeatureVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
```

And then your report writers would implement the IVisitor interface and do whatever it's supposed to do in each type.

To use this, it's look something like this:

```
var writer = new HtmlReportWriter();
foreach(IFeature feature in document) {
    feature.Accept(writer);
}
writer.FinishUp();
```

The way this works is that the first virtual call to Accept resolves back to the concrete type of the feature. The call to the Visit method is NOT virtual - the call to `visitor.Visit(this)` calls the correct overload since at that point it knows the exact static type of the thing that's being visited. No casts and type safety is preserved.

This pattern is great when new visitor types get added. It's much more painful when the elements (features in your case) change - every time you add a new element, you need to update the IVisitor interface and all the implementations. So consider carefully.

As I mentioned, there's been almost 20 years since the book was published, so you can find lots of analysis and improvements on Visitor pattern out there. Helpfully this gives you enough of a start to continue your analysis.

Comment: *every time you add a new element, you need to update the IVisitor interface and all the implementations*, but in this case **you have to rewrite your visitor**.  You've moved the pain, you haven't really lessened it (well, some--its painful, not debilitating).  Better that the component be designed to write its own report or declares its own report writer via attributes, so when you add a new feature you don't have to go rewrite other classes...

Comment: @Will that kind of depends on the specific visitor, doesn't it? If you add a TableFeature, for example, a TextReportWriter might only need to add the one method, while perhaps the PDFReportWriter would require more surgery. I'm not saying Visitor is THE answer or that it's not without problems, that's why i recommend further study. It really depends on how fast the various hierarchies change if this is annoying or fatal.

Answer (score 1):

I would structure this in a slightly different way:

I wod have a `IReport` object that composes all the features in the report. This object would have methods `AddFeature(IFeature)` and `GenerateReport(IReportWriter)`

I would then have `IFeature` implement `WriteFeature(IReport, IReportWriter)` and this way delegate how the Feature is actually processed to the Feature itself.

The way you've structured the code makes me think that there is no way to write a Feature in a format agnostic way that can be processed by any given writer, so let the object itself deal with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid `Visitor` for two reasons: 1) it's complicated and 2) it seems your `IFeature` and `IReportWriter` hierarchies are both open to extension. `Visitor` is only good if the visited `Element` hierarchy is stable. See @Will's comment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32256469/1168342. Simple is also a good design.

Here's what your code looks like in a UML class diagram:

[image: UML class diagram of OP's code]

`AddFeature` seems to be an inconsistent name. What this method is doing is formatting output, so I'd name it appropriately.

If you follow the [Replace conditional with polymorphism](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html) refactoring, you can add an `IFeature.WriteOutput()` method that each concrete Feature will implement. Then your call in `IReportWriter` looks like

```
public void AddFeature(IFeature feature)
{
    InsertSectionBreakIfNeeded();
    feature.WriteOutput();
    sectionBreakNeeded = true;
}
```

In a sense, you've applied only the Strategy pattern to your code, where `IFeature` plays the role of `Strategy` and `IReportWriter` plays the role of Context:

[image: Strategy pattern in UML]

---

### Edit for Abstract Factory

[image: Abstract Factory with WriteMethod() polymorphic call]

It's looking less simple, but your example code didn't really consider all the permutations of [PDF, Text] and [Chart, List].

I suggest the Abstract classes/interfaces of PdfReportFeature and ListReportFeature in case there are some functions like creating a format preamble that would be there. You could possibly apply the Template Method pattern, if needed.

The idea is that each concrete class, e.g., `PdfListFeature`, will have its own `WriteOutput` method that does what it needs to do. The concrete `ReportWriter` just calls `feature.WriteOutput()` for whatever feature is injected (aggregated) into the report.

There's no double-dispatch since you won't be mixing PDF and Text reports together (Visitor really doesn't make sense to me). When you create a report, it's one or the other type. Your Abstract Factory pattern will help you create and pass the proper class for chart or list into the writer.

I updated the Strategy part above to be consistent with the Abstract Factory approach. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: How do you handle that WriteOutput(); behaves differently for different IReportWriter's? Drawing a PDF and writing to plain text are entirely different operations even though you're inserting the same information.

Comment: OK, I didn't pick that point up from your example code. I am wondering if Abstract Factory wouldn't apply for creating your features.

Comment: Creating the features isn't the issue. Indeed I am using an abstract factory to create them. The crux of the question was how to handle that the WriteOutput implementation was dependent both on the Feature and the ReportWriter; so I needed a separate implementation for every permutation of the two. I think the accepted answer (Visitor) is probably the simplest way to address what is a complicated scenario.

Comment: I'll edit my answer with a UML diagram for how I thought Abstract Factory might help.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're trying to draw something (i.e. output it to pdf or text or whatever ...).

My guess would be to go with something like this:

```
interface IReportWriter {
    void AddFeature(IFeature feature);
    // Some other method to generate the output.
    IOutput Render();
    // Drawing primitives that every report writer implements
    void PrintChar(char c);
    void DrawLine(Point begin, Point end);
    ...
}

// Default implementation for ReportWriters
abstract class AbstractReportWriter {
    private IList<IFeature> features = new List<IFeature>();

    ...

    public void AddFeature(IFeature feature) {
        this.features.Add(feature);
    }

    public IOutput Render() {
        foreach(var feature in this.features) {
            feature.RenderOn(this);
        }
    }

    // Leave the primitives abstract
    public abstract void PrintChar(char c);
    public abstract void DrawLine(Point begin, Point end);
}
```

And on the feature side:

```
interface IFeature {
    void RenderOn(IReportWriter);
}
```

And here is an example implementation of `ChartFeature`:

```
public class ChartFeature : IFeature {
    ...
    public void RenderOn(IReportWriter report) {
       // Draw the chart based on the primitives.
       report.DrawLine(..., ...);
       ...
    }
}
```